# How to get AppHarbor application URL including scheme?

Tags: model-view-controller, appharbor

I am trying to retrieve the URL of the application according to the following article: http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/workaround-for-generating-absolute-urls-without-port-number

But... the example uses HTTP as the scheme. In order to try and find HTTPS, I am trying to use Request.Url.Scheme, which always returns "http".
How can I build the real URL of the application including the scheme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppHarbor application servers always see http because SSL is terminated at the load balancers. You can use the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header to check for SSL. [Details](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/tips-and-tricks/ssl-and-certificates) and example [RequireHttpsAttribute](https://gist.github.com/915869). Alternatively, you can use [this module](https://gist.github.com/2025391) to hide away the complexitied of the AppHarbor load balancers.